# Simplifying products of DiracDelta

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, programming, rule, products

I want to simplify expressions containing DiracDelta products. For example I want to simplify the expression
$$\delta(z-2)\delta(k-5)\delta(t-z-k-9)$$
to give the answer
$$\delta(z-2)\delta(k-5)\delta(t-16).$$
I have used Simplify but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: For example if `z==k-3`, then this product is not defined at all (see the documentation to `DiracDelta`). Also the question arises: where do such products appear?

Comment: Let's say I want to force Mathematica to get that answer, how could I do that?

Comment: Is that answer true?

Comment: Yes it's true. We have discussed DiracDelta before in another question and I know your opinion.

Comment: Sorry, I prefer arguments and references over empty words.

Comment: We did before :). And the only reference you prefer is documentation of Mathematica and not textbooks ^^

Comment: `DiracDelta` is a distribution; it is not actually a function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). You can get Mathematica to simplify expressions involving `DiracDelta` by using it inside `Integrate`. Here is an example of this: `Integrate[f[z, k, t] DiracDelta[z - 2] DiracDelta[k - 5] DiracDelta[t - z - k - 9], {z, z1, z2}, {k, k1, k2}, {t, t1, t2}, Assumptions -> {z2 > z1, k2 > k1, t2 > t1}]` which evaluates to give `f[2, 5, 16] UnitStep[2 - z1] UnitStep[-2 + z2] UnitStep[5 - k1, -5 + k2, 16 - t1, -16 + t2]`.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell If you run Simplify[DiracDelta[t-5]/t] in Mathematica you will get DiracDelta[t-5]/5. You can actually do this by hand following the properties of DiracDelta.

Comment: I am writing from the point of view of someone who used to do LOTS of theoretical particle physics products-of-`DiracDelta` manipulations. `Simplify[DiracDelta[t-5]/t]` simplifies to `1/5 DiracDelta[-5 + t]` because Mathematica knows that these two (simple) expressions are equivalent when using `DiracDelta` as a distribution inside an integral. However, Mathematica does NOT know about all equivalences between distributions involving `DiracDelta`.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell how to solve this problem then?

Comment: To define transformation rules that address your problem of simplifying `expr = DiracDelta[z-2] DiracDelta[k-5] DiracDelta[t-z-k-9]` I would start by defining the rule `transf = Times[DiracDelta[Plus[u_,z]], DiracDelta[Plus[v__,z]]] :> Times[DiracDelta[Plus[u,z]], DiracDelta[Plus[v,u]]]`, and then evaluate `expr /. transf` to check that it does what you want. The trick to constructing rules is to look at `FullForm[expr]`, and to then use whichever part of `expr` you want to transform as the lefthand side of the rule, inserting appropriate patterns to make the rule as general as you require.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell Tried it, but unfortunatly it didn't work.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell : Can you elaborate your "You can get Mathematica to simplify expressions involving `DiracDelta` by using it inside Integrate"? Yor reference to Wiki and your example are not clear to me. For example, `Integrate[
 f[z, k, t] DiracDelta[z - 2] DiracDelta[k - 5] DiracDelta[
   t - z - k - 9], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]` considered as the action of the distribution on `f[z,k,t]`, results in `ConditionalExpression[
 DiracDelta[-5 + k] DiracDelta[-2 + z] f[z, k, 9 + k + z], 
 Im[k] + Im[z] == 0]`,

Comment: whereas `Integrate[
 f[z, k, t] DiracDelta[z - 2] DiracDelta[k - 5] DiracDelta[
   t - 16], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]` performs `DiracDelta[-5 + k] DiracDelta[-2 + z] f[z, k, 16]`.

Comment: The `ConditionalExpression` is correct. You have not yet integrated w.r.t. `z` and `k`, so not all of the `DiracDelta` are inside `Integrate`.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell: Are you serious? `Im[k] + Im[z] == 0`allows `k` and `z` to be complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, because it makes `k + z` real, as is required. You have NOT yet integrated w.r.t. `z` and `k` so those variables are still free, but the `t` integral which you HAVE done requires `Im[k] + Im[z] == 0`.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell:  You are not right. Up to [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html?q=DiracDelta) "Function domain of DiracDelta ... is restricted to real arguments:" `FunctionDomain[DiracDelta[z], z, Complexes]` results in `z < 0 || z > 0`.

Comment: I do not automatically use the Wolfram documentation as my primary reference source. If you are unsure about how to handle Dirac delta functions, then simply replace them with a convenient alternative representation such as finite width Gaussian bump functions, do whatever manipulations are needed, then take the limit of zero width. If you are solving physics problems, then this approach makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

**modified**

If we look at a simpler example , with only two unknowns (for reasons of visualization)

`DiracDelta[z-2]DiracDelta[k-z]`

you would conclude

`DiracDelta[z-2]DiracDelta[k-z]=?=DiracDelta[z-2]DiracDelta[k-2]`

Numerical visualization shows

```
dirac = Function[{x, eps}, Exp[-(x^2/(2 eps))]/Sqrt[2 Pi eps]]
Plot3D[dirac[z - 2, #] dirac [k - 2, #] - (dirac[z - 2, #] dirac [k - z, #]), {z, 1, 3}, {k,1, 3}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100] &[.01]
```

[image]

difference (distributial difference) between these two expressions!

Final check

```
NIntegrate[dirac[z - 2, #] dirac[k - 2, #] - (dirac[z - 2, #] dirac[k - z, #]), {z, 1, 3}, {k, 1,3}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] &[.01]
(*-1.46645*10^-8*)
```

evaluates to zero, though  conclusion seems to be is correct!

**addendum**

Back to your original question:

Catch the arguments of `DiracDelta`'s and force them to be zero

```
Cases[DiracDelta[z - 2] DiracDelta[k - 5] DiracDelta[t - z - k - 9],DiracDelta[p_] :> p, -1]
sol = Solve[% == 0, Variables[%]][[1]]
Map[DiracDelta[#] &, sol /. Rule -> Subtract]  /. List -> Times

(*DiracDelta[-5 + k] DiracDelta[-16 + t] DiracDelta[-2 + z]*)
```

Comment: DiracDelta(z-2) is exactly zero except at z=2. Also DiracDelta(k-z) equals zero except at k=0. Then the whole expression is zero except at k=z=2 and hence the answer is TRUE.

Comment: Also you may find the Laplace transform of the expression to verify the answer.

Comment: @MohamedMostafa That might be all true. But my visualization shows a "distributional difference" between the two expressions. Not more.

Comment: Because you plotted an approximation of it.

Comment: @MohamedMostafa  It's only possible to plot numerical approximations of `DiracDelta`, but `Limit[...,eps->0]` doesn't change this observation.

Comment: If you take the limit to zero, all the differences will shrink in a single point and will get no difference at all.

Comment: No I got your point. Your conclusion is correct it intergation around the "peak" vanishs. I'll modify my answer

Comment: if you can help me simplify the expression I would be very thankful:)

Comment: Try to catch the arguments of al `DiracDelta`'s in your expression and solve the equations...

Answer (score 0):

You probably are supposing, the set of Schwarz distributions is forming an algebra with respect to the set of operation (+,*, evaluate at a point) as we use the algebra of functions with rules of addition and multiplication.

Its an extension of functional algebra with severe limitations for distributions with discontiniuties.

This idea rest on the assumptions, that as for

$$(f⊕g)(x)=f(x)+g(x),(f⊗g)(x)=f(x)∗(g(x))$$

which is going ot work everywhere except for local evalution on the support of discontinuities of any of the distribution. The simples non working examples ar $\delta(x) \Theta[x], \delta^2(x)$, while $\theta^2 = \theta$ is working.

The central point is order of evaluation and the continuity there on different paths to the evaluation point.

$$ \delta_x( f ) = f(x),   \delta_x (\delta_y f)  =  \delta_x (f(y)) = f(y)(x) != f(y,x)$$
$$  \delta_y (\delta_x f)  =  \delta_y (f(x)) = f(x)(y) != f(x,y)$$
This problem of evaluation order with definite order of the arguments of a function by named symbols is not only conceptual , but fundamental.

Incontrast to vs 6  (the deleted post), at least since vs 13 Mathematica the problem is known. The list of all 6 permutations of evaluations of an integral with a function of three named variables with definite positions: The integration remains unevaluated, if two $\delta$'s with the same argument collide in a  step of integration per dimension.

The problem of multidimensional integration is tied to the theorem of Fubini.

In vs 13.3 the evaluation on any of the different orders of integration yields

```
    ((# -> (int = 
     Integrate[
       DiracDelta[z - 2] DiracDelta[k - 5] DiracDelta[t-z-k-9] *
      f[z, k, t], #1, #2, #3] &) @@ 
        Permute[{{z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
                 {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
                 {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}}, #] &) /@ 
   Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]) /. 
    {_Integrate :> \[Integral]\[Delta][x] f[x] \[DifferentialD]x}
```

$$\{1,2,3\}\  \to \  f(2,5,16),\qquad \{1,3,2\}\to \int f(x) \delta (x) \, dx,\qquad \{2,1,3\}\ \to \ f(2,5,16) $$

$$ \{2,3,1\}\ \to \  \int f(x) \delta (x) \, dx,\qquad \{3,1,2\}\ \to \ \int f(x) \delta (x) \, dx, \qquad \{3,2,1\}\ \to \ \int f(x) \delta (x) \, dx$$

History: When Heaviside introduced distributional algebra, for some  time, he was the only one able to apply his set of rules producing mathematically correct results. Then he started to study pure mathematics.

Only after Laurent Schwarz introduced distributions as vectors, elements in the dual linear space of evaluation procedures $\mathit S'$ on his Schwarz vector space of smooth functions with compact support $\mathit S_0$, it became clear, what a complex machinery Heaviside had developed in his distribution calculus.

By this theory, product of distributions of different variables are identified as evaluators at a point by their Fourier transformation formulas. Disturbing: The space of distributions contains nearly all integrable, piecewise functions as a core. But limits of series of such functions not converging pointwise everywhere, too.

The multidimensional Schwarz distribution calculus rests on the fact, that for all integrals, order of integration is free. That is Fubini and is working on the space of  smooth functions, integrals over all of 1..n-space existing, only.

Comment: [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Fubini%27s+theorem&title=Special:Search&ns0=1) does not deal with distributions at all.

Comment: Is this a question? How to calculate $\delta(x) \delta(y)$ in polar coordinates? There is no other way  as to use  

$\delta (x,y) = Fourier(e^ {i (k x+ l y}) $